# Unoivot using SQL

Tags: sql, format, pivot, unpivot

this is the code

```
create table info
(id smallint Not Null primary key,name char,date_of_birth date, salary int)

insert into info values ('1', 'sara','2019-02-02', '3000')

insert into info values ('2', 'amir','2019-02-02', '2000')

insert into info values ('3', 'barfi','', '')

insert into info values ('4', 'panbe','', '1000')

insert into info values ('5', 'milow','2020-02-02', '')

insert into info values ('6', '','2021-02-02', '3500')

insert into info values ('7', '','2019-02-02', '2020')

insert into info values ('8', 'ggg','2018-02-02', '4500')

insert into info values ('9', '','', '100')

insert into info values ('10', 'jjj','', '5000')
```

For example the first rows must be:

```
1   name   roya

1   date_of_birth   2019-02-02

1   salary   3000

2   name   amir

.
.
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution uses `union all`:

```
select id, 'name' as which, name as value, 
from info
union all
select id, 'date_of_birth' as which, cast(date_of_birth as varchar(255)), 
from info
union all
select id, 'salary' as which, cast(salary as varchar(255))
from info;
```

Comment: thanks for answering. I've done it using union all, I could not go further. So I tried to use unpivot

Comment: @Sara . . . I'm not sure what your comment means.  You should also tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I am a new user and I don't know exactly hoe should I ask questions here. I mean I know using union all is a generic solution to this problem, but I could not solve it. That's why I am trying to use unpivot.